# How to get MySQL to throw error when drop partition needs to wait

Tags: mysql, partitioning

MySQL innodb table, partitioned on a datetime column, basically just a logging table.

When I attempt to reorganize or drop a partition, (Which needs an exclusive metadata lock) I want the query to timeout after a few seconds and throw an error, which I can then catch, and retry later/alert whoever is in charge of the server/etc. Is there a good/easy way to do this, or do I need to spin up another thread to watch the partitioning thread, killing the query if it takes too long?

(Background: We had a problem where all queries to a table would hang on "Waiting for table metadata lock". This was tracked down to a transaction that was never closed, preventing the hourly partitioning code from locking the table, while prevent anything else from getting access. The code at fault was modified, but I would like the partitioning system to stay up under those circumstances.)

Answer (score -1):

Please provide details of the partitioning and selects.  You may be doing things such that all actions are locking all partitions all the time.

Use `PARTITION BY RANGE` and do `DROP PARTITION` to remove the oldest, plus `REORGANIZE` a "future", empty, partition into the next hour plus a new "future".

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for more details.